# Voxelization Visualizer

Tags: data-visualization

I have a voxelization I need to visualize.

I know:

- The x,y,z position the voxel grid starts at (not that it matters)
- The total number of voxels
- The width of the voxel grid in each direction (not necessarily equal)
- Whether each voxel is active (1) or inactive (0)
- The width of a single voxel

My current method has just been printing out the results as X,Y slices of 1's and 0's for each Z and looking at it. This isn't sufficient though. I tried gnuplot but it quickly slows down with large numbers of points, and I'm not sure if it worked and my voxelization was wrong, or vice-versa. Doesn't seem to match the printouts. It's not really made for that.

I need some tool that can take in an input file I can write with this information, and turn it into something I can visually look at, turn around, etc.

I know of [viewvox](http://www.patrickmin.com/viewvox/), but the 3 links it provides to "file formats" do not read as file formats at all and lack examples of those formats, making it very hard to tell which, if any, I could use.

Anyone know of anything else? Simpler solutions would be better.